# How do you listen for new direct messages using Twitter4J now that twitter disabled the user/site streams

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm working on a way for my twitter bot to listen for new direct messages being sent to the twitter the bot is connected to, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555573/does-twitter4j-provide-event-listener-for-incoming-direct-messages) and I tried it out.

But I found out that twitter has disabled user/site streams around 2 months ago, and I've been googling for an answer the entire yesterday and this morning and I can't find anything on how to listen for direct messages now with java

Hoping there are some that have figured it out or can help me in the right direction to figure out this issue

Here's my auth code if that's needed and I'm using twitter4j v4.0.7 (core & stream)

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(config.get("twitter.consumer-key"))
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(config.get("twitter.consumer-key-secret"))
                .setOAuthAccessToken(config.get("twitter.access-token"))
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(config.get("twitter.access-token-secret"));

        Configuration builtConfig = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(builtConfig);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        TwitterStreamFactory twitterStreamFactory = new TwitterStreamFactory(builtConfig);
        stream = twitterStreamFactory.getInstance();

        stream.addListener(new TwitterListener(twitter, sql));
        stream.user();

        twitter.help().getAPIConfiguration();
        Bot.log("Twitter manager successfully setup.");
```

The twitter listener is just a normal UserStreamListener that prints out the message if it gets a DM

Comment: You'll need to wait for Twitter4J to support the new Account Activity API that supports this kind of interaction. I believe the author is working on it, but it may not be available yet. User streams can no longer be connected to or used.

The alternative would be to use the REST API to poll for Direct Messages instead.

Comment: @AndyPiper Any update received from Twitter4j regarding this issue ?

Comment: Twitter4j is an Open Source project on GitHub, I have not been looking at it regularly as I don't use it often. I would recommend asking on GitHub or any of the project mailing lists as I do not work on the project.